# Is there a reason why Marvel doesn't take action against DC (or vice-versa)?

Tags: marvel, dc

In the CW's series The Flash, we see Cisco Ramon, and in some instances even Felicity Smoak use the references to Marvel characters such as Spider-man, The Incredible Hulk and many others.

On the other hand, in Raimi's Spider-man 2002, we see Peter Parker also call out Shazam! in an attempt to shoot his webbing (reference to DC's Captain Marvel or SHAZAM).

My question is, is there a reason Marvel (or Disney) doesn't sue CW or DC for using their character references? Or is there some sort of mutual coordination between the two.

Comment: a) why sue someone for treating your IP as iconic and essentially giving you free advertising? & b) don't look like a jerk by suing someone for doing that.

Comment: There's a big, big difference between referencing another company's character in passing, and using that other company's character as an on-screen character in your movie.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's not something they can take legal action on. Merely mentioning a character that belongs to someone else is considered fair use of trademarked terms so long as you aren't doing something like trying to denigrate the trademarked product or something similar.

It's the same way Claire on the *The Orville* can refer to herself acting as the Obi-Wan for another character without worrying about Disney coming to sue, why Jack O'Neill on *Stargate SG-1* could make references to *The Simpsons*, why Kenzie and Deeks on *NCIS Los Angeles* could refer to Bizarro (and explicitly state who Bizarro is), why Bill could have a long discussion about Superman/Clark Kent in *Kill Bill vol 2*, why characters can mention brand names of cars, and so on.

So having Jax and Stein talk about Spider-Man is fine so long as they aren't having a conversation about how lame Spider-Man is, or something similar.

Comment: I doin't think that even saying things like "Spider-Man" sucks would bring a lawsuit - characters in movies are allowed to have opinions: Eric Cartman hates "Family Guy", Randal from "Clerks 2" badmouths LOtR to hell and back, Cassidy from "Preacher" keeps saying that "Big Lebowski" was a lame movie etc, etc...

Comment: @Yasskier, It probably wouldn't win a lawsuit or be worth the time to even file one, but it is the sort of thing that, theoretically, be used to make the claim even if no one does. It's notable that in the comic character references, Marvel and DC (well, Disney and WB) generally avoid dissing one another's characters unless it's a straight parody.

Answer (score 3):

You can generally do this under [fair use](https://fairuse.stanford.edu/overview/fair-use/what-is-fair-use/)

> In its most general sense, a fair use is any copying of copyrighted material done for a limited and “transformative” purpose, such as to comment upon, criticize, or parody a copyrighted work. Such uses can be done without permission from the copyright owner. In other words, fair use is a defense against a claim of copyright infringement. If your use qualifies as a fair use, then it would not be considered an infringement.

Now, there's nothing stopping Disney from suing DC over the references to their characters ([the BBC is currently being sued for using clips of *The Cosby Show*](https://arstechnica.com/tech-policy/2017/11/bbc-makes-a-doc-about-bill-cosby-rape-allegations-gets-sued-over-copyright/) in a documentary they produced), but it's pretty unlikely Disney would prevail. Simply mentioning The Hulk is not generally considered copyright infringement. Even having Flash beat up on a giant, green, inflatable man would be hard to prove.

> Raimi's Spider-man 2002, we see Peter Parker also call out Shazam! in an attempt to shoot his webbing (reference to DC's Captain Marvel or SHAZAM).

This is an even weaker case than mentioning The Hulk. I mean, the Andy Griffith character [Gomer Pyle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gomer_Pyle) made it part of his schtick. So one could argue [the word has become too generic](https://arstechnica.com/tech-policy/2017/08/supreme-court-asked-to-nullify-the-google-trademark/)

> Words like teleprompter, thermos, hoover, aspirin, and videotape were once trademarked. They lost the status after their names became too generic and fell victim to what is known as "genericide."

It's a harder case to make for genericide, but either way, DC would have to explain why it was OK for Gomer Pyle to say it for years, but not for Toby MacGuire to say it once.